# The argument type 'List<BatchRecord>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<BatchTiming>'

Tags: flutter, dart

The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable'. I am facing the issue while try to add data to a list.

```
getBatchDates() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);

      var batchDates = await api.getUserEnrollmentBatches();

      if (batchDates != null) {
        return BatchDate.assignAll(batchDates);
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that List is not implementing Iterable. You have to add the values manually. Im not familar with futter classes, but I think it should be possible in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **`api.getUserEnrollmentBatches()`** is returning **`List<BatchDate>`**, then use **`_myList.addAll(batchDates)`** instead `BatchDate.assignAll(batchDates)`.

```
var List<BatchDate> _myList = []; // Something inside

List<BatchDate> getBatchDates() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);

      var batchDates = await api.getUserEnrollmentBatches();

      if (batchDates != null) {
        return _myList.addAll(batchDates);
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A List class implemets Iterable class. They arnot the same thing. You have to change your List to Iterable. But also if your class BatchRecord isn't a subclass of BatchTiming you also won't be able to assign it to parameter

Comment: BatchTiming is the subclass of BatchRecord.

`batchTiming: List<BatchTiming>.from(
            json["batch_timing"].map((x) => BatchTiming.fromJson(x))),`